# Dialog doesn't appears when Homeactivity in already running android

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I am in a certain issues that the Dialog doesn't appears when Homeactivity in already running

My app flow

Normal flow( without push notification )

SplashActivity-->AdScreen-->HomeActivity-->RateDialog(if user still not rated)--------> works perfect as expected

Flow with push notification (app not running) -- when user clicks on the notification

SplashActivity(skipped)-->HomeActivity-->LuckyDrawDilaog

The problem is when app is already running Dialog doesn't appears on click of notification , but HomeActivity appears.

```
public class HomeActiviy extends TabActivity implements OnClickListener {

onCreate(....){
new PerformGetLuckyDraw().execute(); // code to launch LuckyDrawDilaog 
}

}
```

Comment: you need to set splash activity when user clicks on notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code in onResume() method instead of onCreate()

```
 new PerformGetLuckyDraw().execute();
```

Comment: And also how to close the previously opened HomeActivity .... I am using Xtify for push notification

Comment: use finish() on onPause() method.

Comment: if " finish() on onPause() " is solution for only notification issues , then this would create problem if other activity is opened with HomeActivity

Comment: you can set a boolean variable for that purpose

Comment: I am sorry to say this bro .... " Use following code in onResume() method instead of onCreate()

 new PerformGetLuckyDraw().execute(); " .... not working now ..I don;t know what happned